# How to setup a Windows 7 folder so that everything in there is shared automatically?

Tags: windows-7, shared-folders

I have a folder somewhere on my `D>` drive that I would like to share with everybody on my network.

When I right click the folder and share it with everybody, all the files are shared correctly. The problem is when I add a new file I have to explicitly tell it to share that as well. I want this process to be done automatically.

Everything in folder Foo is to be shared at all times.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: You should be able to share the parent folder and anything added to that folder would then share those priviliages. Thats how my media center folder works at least.

Comment: How are these files being added?  Created in that folder, copied in, or moved in?

Comment: @techie007: The files are copied in with Ctrl + V

Comment: Ctrl-V is Paste. :)  Before pasting were they Copied (ctrl-c) or Moved (ctrl-x)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right click Foo, and turn on Share. I'm assuming you are not using Simple Share

You'll also want to add the group "Everyone" to the Share permissions. Click the Advaned Sharing then Permission. Give the "Everyone" group either **read** or **full control**.
Ok and next go to the Security Tab. Click Edit and Add the Everyone group there.  Give them Read permissions.

That will let anyone on the network have read access to the file.  If you want to grant write, make sure you grant write or full control permission under share permission.

In the end it just makes more sense to grant full control under Share permissions and then use the Security tab to set the file permissions there. The file permission under the Security tab(sometimes referred to as the ACL) trumps Share permissions.

Comment: Is there a way to automate this so that new folders or files added to a share automatically inherit the parent's Security permissions? For example, if I already have a share set up with your steps above, and I add a file/folder to that share (using a copy/paste), why won't it automatically inherit the parent's permissions?

Comment: The folder you move into that share will inherit the existing **share** permissions but will **not inherit NTFS** permissions (that's where you go under the Security tab).  Inherited NTFS permissions are only set at the object's creation, otherwise you'd get into weird situations since folders can live under one or more parents. You can get around this by just making a separate copy under the Share and then making a symlink or junction to your normal working folder.